# Последовательность натуральних чисел

Tags: c++

Надо написать программу, которая в последовательности натуральных чисел определяет сумму всех чисел, кратных 6 и оканчивающихся на 4. Программа получает на вход натуральные числа, количество введённых чисел неизвестно,  последовательность чисел заканчивается числом 0 (0 — признак окончания ввода, не входит в последовательность).Sample Input:24 16 36 144 64 44 0 24 54 84 24
Sample Output:168.У меня виводит : 144

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    system("chcp 1251>nul");
    int n,s=0;
    cin >> n;
    while (n != 0) {
        cin >> n;
        if ((n % 6 == 0) && (n % 10 == 4)) {
            s =s+ n;
        }
        }
    

    cout << s;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Может это поможет? https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/debugger/?view=vs-2019

Comment: Внутри цикла `while` строку `cin >> n;` разместите **после** условия `if`. Сейчас самое первое считанное число последовательности (перед циклом `while`) игнорируется. [Пример](https://ideone.com/hv5QCh).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Уберите

```
cin >> n;
```

до цикла - а то первое значение игнорируется.

Не изменяя логики, можно просто начальное значение n задать ненулевое

Comment: еще укажите чтобы проинициализировал n нулем

Comment: @MBo
Да спасибо большое , тупанул

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch Как раз не нулём, если код цикла не менять

Comment: @MBo ах да, верно

Comment: Извините а могли б оценить вопрос @MBo ,@Andrej Levkovitch, а то не понимаю почему -1